# Last typed text box identity

Tags: jquery

I have a form like this

```
<div>
     <input type="text" data-identity-td="uk-021">
     <input type="text" data-identity-td="ae-033">
     <input type="text" data-identity-td="fr-045">
     <input type="text" data-identity-td="in-125">
</div>
```

if i type anything any of the textbox  eg: if i type something in third text box the

`data-identity-td="fr-045"` after click the outside of the text box need to get a message

**"You typed something in fr-045"**

any jquery solution for this?

Comment: A simple `blur` event handler …?

Comment: I'd suggest you read the jQuery documentation, as even just a basic glance through the method names would probably give you enough information about what you need to do: http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple JQuery to achieve this. You need to use `focusout` event:

```js
$('input').on('focusout', function(){
  $('.message').text('You typed something in ' + $(this).data('identity-td'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-identity-td="uk-021">
  <input type="text" data-identity-td="ae-033">
  <input type="text" data-identity-td="fr-045">
  <input type="text" data-identity-td="in-125">
</div>
<div class='message'></div>
```

Comment: Possible caveat though - this shows the 'you typed something' message even if you just click on an input, then off it again